# Remove query phrase from output for stemming query elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I just started with elastic search. it is working properly for everything but I want stemming result not contains search phrase

example if I search **consult** then I got result **consult** , **consultant**
So I want only **consultant**

```
 "filter": {
    "my_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "light_german"
    }
  }
```

Can I change type : stemmer ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your required use case is to use multi fields.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "content":"consult"
}
{
    "content":"consultant"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "content": "consult"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "content.exact": "consult"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65701139",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "content": "consultant"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: But same document contains both words then.?